# JMeter HTML dashboard report not showing up 99.9th percentile (float)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have updated user.properties to display following percentile values. However the html report generated is not taking 99.9th percentile instead showing up two 99th percentile columns. It can take any int number like 98th or 92nd percentile but not taking a float number.

Is this a bug? or Am I missing something? Appreciate any help on this.

aggregate_rpt_pct1=95

aggregate_rpt_pct2=99

aggregate_rpt_pct3=**99.9**

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest [JMeter 5.4.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-4-1-released-td5739226.html)

[image]

I don't know where did you put these properties overrides, just in case they should go to *user.properties* file and JMeter restart will be required to apply them.

Another option is passing the custom percentiles via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jaggregate_rpt_pct1=95 -Jaggregate_rpt_pct2=99 -Jaggregate_rpt_pct3=99.9 -n -t test.jmx -f -l result.jtl -e -o dashboard
```

And last but not the least, it might be the case you're looking into "old" dashboard, try providing `-f` argument so JMeter would delete existing dashboard folder and generate a brand new one.

More information:

- [Full List of JMeter Command Line Options](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was using JMeter 5.2 but upgrading it to 5.3 or 5.4 just worked fine. Thanks again.